# WPF Taking control of tooltip popups

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I am working on a simple text editor that allows the user to hover over words in the text and get information about them. I am looking for a way to control a tooltip that pops up based on my own logic the drives from the MouseMove event. Trying to create a simple popup that acts similar to a code editing window when you are debugging and looking at variable symbol values by hovering the mouse over words in the text.

I am not seeing an obvious way to force the tooltip to show/hide on-demand.

Comment: WPF **ToolTipService** class provides many means of finetuning ToolTip behaviour and appearance etc. Including setting the display duration to virtually forever.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `ToolTip` property, you could use a [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/popup-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) element and set its `IsOpen` property to control when you want to display it.

You can style it to look like a `ToolTip`.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be a much better approach thus far.